# Jquery hovered item over 'a' tag

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a link element and when you hover over it a div appears. This div is meant to be over the link element. When I move my mouse the div that is showing flickers. Is there a way to fix this. I am assuming it is beacuse the div is now covering the link element.

Thanks,
C

Comment: a code sample would really help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using some code like this:

```
$("a").hover(function () { // Enter
    $("div").show();
}, function () { // Leave
    $("div").hide();
});
```

In this case, your guess is correct. If the `div` is floating over the `a`, the mouse leave is triggered when the `div` is displayed, because the mouse starts to be on the `div` and not on the `a`. Then, the `div` is hided, the mouse enter the `a` again... And all begins another time.

If you can avoid the `div` to appear over (with z-index, for example), it'll be more simple.

Otherwise, I suggest you do something like this:

```
$("a").mouseenter(function () {
    $("div").show();
});

$("div").mouseleave(function () {
    $("div").hide();
});
```

If your mouse will be always over the `div` when it's opened, then it can close itself if the mouse leaves.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it is incorrect - he is doing the opposite, fading in on hover, so this would actually work, with event bubbling. On a side note, what you should actually do it to attach the hover event to the parent, and let bubbling do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not testing to see if the `div` is already visible or not. You test visibility using the following code:

```
if ($("div").is(":hidden")) {
    // make div visible here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Here is the code I am now using...

$('area,#map-zoom').hover(function(){
        $('#map-zoom').show();
    },function() {
        $('#map-zoom').hide();
    });

I have added the hover function to the appearing div aswell.